# making a function that have two parameters, start number and the end number and should return the count of all numbers except numbers with a 5 in it

Tags: php, count, largenumber

I have asked to make a function that have two parameters, start number and
the end number and should return the count of all numbers
except numbers with a 5 in it. The start and the end number are
both inclusive!

The start number will always be smaller than the end
number. Both numbers can be also negative!
The end number may be a very big integer value like 10^9

any suggestions?

Comment: Your `$num /= 10` just asymptotically approaches `0`, but will never reach `0`…

Comment:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to check a string representing the number? Something like `str_contains("$num", "5")`? In case the `$num` goes to scientific notation you have to format the number. However, I'm sure the occurrence of the number 5 follows a fixed pattern, so using that you can probably calculate it quickly.

Comment: Such questions _always_ target a solution that does _not_ require to iterate over all numbers in the given interval. Instead you should find a way to combine a logic based on divisions. For a given interval you need to eliminate all numbers that can be divided by 5 and all numbers in the ranges with a a "5" in any of the leading positions. So the resulting algorithm should _not_ have to actually iterate over all numbers.

Comment: @Salwa, please don't fundamentally change the question in a way that invalidates current answers.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware comparing strings is not efficient in large numbers

Comment: @Salwa Trying to solve it and it could take a while. The solution I am trying is only for a positive range. For negative ranges, you can simply take absolute values and get the same answer.

Comment: @Salwa Check the code here I just added. https://github.com/vivek-23/notes/blob/master/php/php_in_action/NumNotContaining5.php For large input, just call `getRangeCount($start, $end)`. Don't call it with `bruteForce` method as it is only made for testing purposes. For negative ranges, just take absolute values and the answer is the same as that of the positive range.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250397/discussion-on-question-by-salwa-making-a-function-that-have-two-parameters-star).

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems in you current code.  The first is as pointed out, just dividing a number by 10 causes the number to start having decimal places. This means it will almost always be > 0.

SO you could change that to use `floor` to round it down...

```
$num = floor($num / 10);
```

The other problem you have is in your comparison -

```
if ($num != 5 || !isDigitPresent($num, 5))
```

With or (`||`) as soon as it finds a true value, it stops checking the rest of the condition (as the result will still be true), so the `isDigitPresent()` will not be called if `$num` is != 5 (which is most of the time.)  So this should be shortened to

```
if (!isDigitPresent($num, 5))
```

There are all sorts of alternatives to this, but based on what you doing you could use...

```
$count = 0;
$digit = 5;
// range() generates an array with the values instead of writing your own
foreach (range(4, 17) as $num) {
    // Check if the digit is any of the characters in the string representation
    if (in_array($digit, str_split($num))) {
        echo $num . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo 'not containg digit:' . $count;
```

Comment: Will this be efficient enough for range till 10^9?

Comment: I have tried this solution but it is not enough for range till 10^9